# how to use v-on=$listeners for click native

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have this in my child component.

`child.vue`

```
<router-link v-on="testone" :to="to">
        <slot/>
</router-link>

computed:{
        testone(){
            let vm = this;

            return Object.assign({},
                this.$listeners,
                {
                    'click.native': function(e){
                        console.log("nice one really");
                        vm.$emit('click');
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    },
```

`parent.vue`

```
    <child.vue @click='testFunction'>Button</child.vue

   testFunction(){
     console.log("good");
    }
```

But what happens is on the parent, @click event doesn't get executed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `testFunction`? What is `_handleClick`? Please include all relevant code and any error message.

Comment: i updated it. take a look.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? So far I see that you never bind click to anything... assigning it to listeners is not enough.

Comment: it's enough :) if it was a button instead of router-link and click instead of click.native in computed property, it would work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having the same exact problem...